# Translate specific return query into mgo

Tags: regex, mongodb, go, mgo

I have a query which returns all names from a collection's documents which contain a specific text. In the following example, return all names which contain the sequence "oh" case-insensitively; do not return other fields in the document:

```
find({name:/oh/i}, {name:1, _id:0})
```

I have tried to translate this query into mgo:

```
Find([]bson.M{bson.M{"name": "/oh/i"}, bson.M{"name": "1", "_id": "0"}})
```

but there are always zero results when using mgo. What is the correct syntax for such a query using mgo?

This question is different from the alleged duplicates because none of those questions deal with how to restrict MongoDB to return only a specific field instead of entire documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute queries that use regexp patterns for filtering, use the [`bson.RegEx`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#RegEx) type.

And to exclude fields from the result documents, use the [`Query.Select()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Select) method.

Like in this example:

```
c.Find(bson.M{"name": bson.RegEx{Pattern: "oh", Options: "i"}}).
    Select(bson.M{"name": 1, "_id": 0})
```

Translation of the regexp:

```
name:/oh/i
```

This means to match documents where the `name` field has a value that contains the `"oh"` sub-string, case insensitive. This can be represented using a `bson.RegEx`, where the `RegEx.Pattern` field gets the pattern used in the above expression (`"oh"`). And the `RegEx.Options` may contain options now to apply / match the pattern. The doc lists the possible values. If the `Options` field contains the `'i'` character, that means to match case insensitive.

If you have a user-entered term such as `"[a-c]"`, you have to quote regexp meta characters, so the final pattern you apply should be `"\[a-c\]"` To do that easily, use the [`regexp.QuoteMeta()`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#QuoteMeta) function, e.g.

```
fmt.Println(regexp.QuoteMeta("[a-c]")) // Prints: \[a-c\]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rUEgy8gzb8K).

Comment: Bullseye. Might be nice to add how to properly escape the specific RegEx format that is being used here.

Comment: @Zyl Added explanation, but the doc of [`bson.RegEx`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#RegEx) details it which should be read anyway.

Comment: The `Pattern` field is interpreted as RE2, no? How would I escape any arbitrary string that may be provided by a user? E.g. escape "[a-c]" so that it matches "[a-c]" instead of "a", "b" and "c".

Comment: Neat. This is quite important because MongoDB uses PCRE, which is not O(n) with n = length of tested string, so this would open up a DDOS attack vector if not escaped. Didn't imagine the function to be called anything that doesn't contain "Escape", so I didn't find it.