# How to escape whitespaces with regex search in golang service using mongodb?

Tags: regex, mongodb, go

I am using [mgo](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/mgo.v2@v2.0.0-20190816093944-a6b53ec6cb22) driver.
"/^\s+text\s+$/i" this is the regex pattern I want to search in the mongo db.

I tried with [MustCompile](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#MustCompile) and Options:"i". But it's not working, there is no data coming.

Code for reference.[code](https://go.dev/play/p/KdcU7sqBuND)

Any string with any number of leading or trailing spaces should come in the result. Example "    text  " should come in the result.

I tried MustCompile, QuoteMeta.

Comment: Just wondering ... Why not use the [official MongoDB _Go_ Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/)?

Comment: See possible duplicate: [Translate specific return query into mgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815987/translate-specific-return-query-into-mgo/49817292#49817292). And a friendly advice: dump `mgo`, use the official driver!